# Path fibration over a connected manifold.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold. We can consider $P(M):=\{\gamma:[0,1] \to M\}$, so we have a natural projection on $M$
$$ P(M) \to M $$
$$ \gamma \mapsto \gamma(1) ,$$
in the fibre of this application what have we the space $\Omega(M;p,q)$ of piecewise $C^\infty$ paths from $p$ to $q$ or the space $\Omega(M;p,p)$ of piecewise $C^\infty$ from $p$ to $p$?
I know that $\Omega(M;p,q)$ is homotopically equivalenti to $\Omega(M;p,p)$.

Comment: The fiber over $p$ is all paths that end in $p$.

Comment: @Marek But if I fix the begin point, say $q$, in $P(M)$, the fiber is $\Omega(M;p,q)$? And $P(M)$ with compact open topology remains contractile?

Comment: But you didn't say anywhere in the OP you were fixing anything. If you fix the beginning as, say, $q$ then fiber over $p$ will naturally be paths from $q$ to $p$. But this is obvious. What is your question really? PM is contractible, just contract every path to one of its endpoints..